# How to move WPF UserControl from one window to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, window

Let's say I have a UserControl called MyVideoControl located in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window Name="_mainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <MyVideoControl Name="_localVideo"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now a user clicks a button and I want the UserControl to float on top of the MainWindow.xaml, inside a newly created window called PopUp.xaml.

```
<Window Name="_popUpWindow">
    <Grid>
        <MyVideoControl Name="_localVideo"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I accomplish this, so the entire object gets moved?  Currently I use XAML to declaratively place MyVideoControl inside my windows, but I'm guessing I'll need to do everything programatically?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Have you seen this functionality elsewhere? I am pretty sure that all controls must be contained in one (and only one) Window.

Comment: you can simply remove user control from man window and add it to new window when user click on button.

Comment: @Jras - perhaps I wasn't clear.  The control will be contained in one (and only one) Window **at any given time**.  So at one point it will be MainWindow, but at another it will be PopUpWindow.  There's only one instance, but it gets moved around the two windows.

Comment: @Eternal21 I was confused with the verbiage "float on top of the MainWindow.xaml". When reading it I imagined the control physically leaving the window and floating to the new window through some sort of wpf transition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do this by removing the `userControl` from the `Mainwindow` and adding it as a logical child to any of the control in the `PopupWin` window.

[image]

***UserControl.xaml:***

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBlock1" Text="hai"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

***MainWindow.xaml :***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="555">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="mainPanel" Orientation="Vertical ">
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
            <WpfApplication1:UserControl1 x:Name="myUserControl" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

***PopupWin.xaml :***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.PopupWin"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PopupWin" Height="300" Width="300">

    <StackPanel x:Name="mainPanel"/>

</Window>
```

***PopupWin.xaml.cs:*** Expose a new constructor to accept `userControl` and add it as a child to the `mainPanel`

```
public partial class PopupWin : Window
{
    public PopupWin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private UserControl control;

    public PopupWin(UserControl control)
        : this()
    {
        this.control = control;

        this.mainPanel.Children.Add(this.control);
    }
}
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs*** On Button_Click remove the userControl from the current `MainWindow` and pass it to `PopupWin`, in this case via constructor.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainPanel.Children.Remove(this.myUserControl);

        var wind = new PopupWin(this.myUserControl);

        wind.ShowDialog();
    }
```

***Note:*** The `userControl` instance should always be a logical child of only `one` element at anytime.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because it's a nice compromise between still being able to use XAML, and yet not having to resort to resource dictionary, with very little code behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `UserControl` a resource you can do this.

Example:

App.Xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication10.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ContentControl x:Key="sharedContent">
            <Label Content="StackOverFlow" />
        </ContentControl>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="325" Width="422" Name="UI">

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Open PopUp" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource sharedContent}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

PopUp Window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.PopupWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PopupWindow" Height="300" Width="300" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication10">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource sharedContent}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way this can be accomplished, using a dynamic layout...

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Button ControlToMove { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create button
        ControlToMove = new Button();

        //add text to button
        ControlToMove.Content = "Click to move me to pop up window";

        //add a new routed event to the buttons click property
        ControlToMove.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MoveControlToPopUp);

        //add control to the layout grid
        MainGrid.Children.Add(ControlToMove);
    }

    //This method moves the button to a popup window
    private void MoveControlToPopUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the name of the control from sender
        var control = sender as Button;
        var controlName = control.Name;

        //checks to see if this is the control we want moved
        //if its not, method exits
        if (controlName != ControlToMove.Name) return;

        //create copy of the control
        var copiedControl = control;

        //remove control from existing window
        MainGrid.Children.Remove(control);

        //create pop up window
        var popUpWindow = new PopUpWindow(copiedControl);
        popUpWindow.Show();
    }
}

public class PopUpWindow : Window
{
    public Grid Layout { get; set; }
    public PopUpWindow(Button button)
    {
        //create a grid for the new window
        Layout = new Grid();

        //add control to grid
        Layout.Children.Add(button);

        //add grid to window
        this.AddChild(Layout);
    }
}
```

}

The only thing I didn't do there was adding the capability to move the button back to main window when it is clicked in the popup window.